# (Rx.Net) Caching the data till an IObserver subscribes

Tags: system.reactive

I have a hot Observable (Rx.Net) that ticks when it detects a device connection to PC. I have a view that handles the display of these devices. Unfortunately, the View may not be displayed until after the devices are connected, and hence, missing the notifications.

I am wondering if there is a way to cache the device connections until someone subscribes. I thought of using `ReplaySubject`, however it keeps on adding to the cache and is not ideal if there are too many device connections over the life of the application session.

Answer (score 0):

Observables use deferred execution and don't produce values until they are subscribed to.

So, you have two choices.

(1) Only connect to the device when you subscribe.

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    Observable
        .Using(() => new Resource(), r => r.Values);
```

The `Using` operation does exactly that. So does `Defer`. Both can be used to delay the connection until there's a subscription.

(2) If the device produces values before you can subscribe then use regular, non-Rx code to cache the values and then have the observable drain the cache when the subscription occurs.

If you need more of an answer than that the you need to provide code that shows the issue you're facing and then I can write code that perhaps solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for the same purpose. Note, that if no subscriber arrives - it should be stopped explicitly by signaling "stopMe" parameter.

The behavior is as following:

1. Starts collecting items until subscribed
2. When subscribed - releases collected items
3. If unsubscribed - **continues to collect items until next subscribe!**
4. Once triggered - should be stopped explicitly by stopMe argument.

   ```
   public static IObservable<T> CollectUntilSubscribed<T, TUntil>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<TUntil> stopMe)
   {
    var subscribersCount = 0;

    var ready = new Subject<Unit>();

    var delayed = source
        .Delay(x => subscribersCount > 0 ? Observable.Return(Unit.Default):ready)
        .Publish()
        ;

    var connection = delayed.Connect();

    stopMe.Take(1).Subscribe(_ => connection.Dispose());

    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var sub = delayed.Subscribe(o);

        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref subscribersCount) == 1) ready.OnNext(Unit.Default);

        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref subscribersCount);
            sub.Dispose();
        });
    });
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Given that the view is going to be shown always one might think of this like:

```
connections.Buffer(view.WhenDisplayed()).Take(1).SelectMany(buffer=>buffer.Concat(connections))
```

Comment: There's nothing here that subscribes to the observable that enables it to cache. You need to show a working example.